# Why fatal error “LNK1104: cannot open file 'cryptlib.lib' occur when I compile a C++ project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I am getting the error mentioned above when compiling a project on Visual Studio. What is strange and different about my situation is that this works on my personal laptop, but not at work.

I have the entire project saved in Dropbox, because I sometimes work on my projects from work and I like this automatic sync that way I don't worry about loosing anything. Having said that, I use relative paths for my libraries, that way the folder is the same for both computers, i.e. "..\cryptopp\x64\Output\Debug\cryptlib.lib"

My question is, why does it work at home, but not at work? I made sure the property sheet has the correct path as well. The linker and VC++ directories are both relative paths.

This cryptlib.lib has some namespaces like CryptoPP and variable types such as byte, it won't give me an error on this. It knows it exists (I get the correct font color)

Is there something that I am missing?

P.S. Added screenshots per request. Can't add more than 2 links, so I merged 2 screenshots into 1. That ECE427Projects is where the solution file is located. I don't want to go any further back than that.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4a6i.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8Gxw.png)

Comment: Could you give us screen shots of A) the directory, including the full path, where the library is located, B) the path variables defined in Visual Studio, including the path that directs to where the libraries are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the directory for the library in the wrong field.

There's two places you could use to specify the directory where your libraries are supposed to be. I prefer to use the **Library Directories** section in **Configuration Properties**→**VC++ Directories**, but the alternate is **Additional Library Directories** in **Configuration Properties**→**Linker**→**General**. There's no need to specify it in both locations, though I doubt anything bad will happen if you do. Bear in mind that this is supposed to be a directory, not a file, so delete the trailing `cryptlib.lib` file name from this directory string.

If you haven't, in **Configuration Properties**→**Linker**→**Input**, for **Additional Dependencies**, you should be putting the name of the library object (`cryptlib.lib`), in your case.

For all of these, make sure the default values inherited by the project property pages are still there, after the stuff you add.

Let me know if this doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: It looks like putting the directory of the library on the VCC++ Library Directory worked like a charm. I'll be removing the library from the Linker path to remove the redundancy. I do have a question somewhat related. The path that I will be putting on the VCC+ Directory, does it matter if I end in a backslash or not?

Comment: @Maty From my testing, it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Ah, that's what I got too. I just wanted to know technically what is the difference, might matter at some point in the future. Either way, thank you very much for your assistance.